# How to know there are 0 result in select

Tags: sql-server

if I have a SQL scripts to check a select statement on a table & output those conditions that has no result, How do I do this. I have variables & fetch & next to go thru each row in the table.

**Example:**

```
declare @1 varchar(10)
declare @2 varchar(10)

declare @1 cursor for
select userid from users

declare @2 cursor for
select pay from pays where pay_userid=@1
```

then here if there is no records in pays for certain userid, output to screen or
I did insert into a temp table

But my issue/problem is not those userids not found will not be output due to the result for the last query has no result for those userids.

Comment: Sorry mate, but my head spinned while reading this.

Comment: get the count of the records..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ....." at first to judge if there is any result in the  query.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `COUNT` of your query, and then check if that `COUNT is > 0`, do your `SELECT`, otherwise, do something else.

Answer (score 0):

```
FETCH NEXT FROM your_cursor;

IF @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  -- do your stuff
END
```

Answer (score 0):

After select statement you can check @@ROWCOUNT variable like this:

```
SELECT ...
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 
    PRINT 'select statement returned empty result'
```